# method change ajax with django

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django

I have the following inputs:

```
<input id="country_name" type"text" />
<input id="country_id" type"text" />
```

And I want to affect the id corresponding to the country that I insert into the `country_name` input with onchange.
So I use this ajax function :

```
$("#country_name").change({
    $.ajax({
        url: "/country/getid/",
        method: 'GET',
        datatype: "json",
        data: {'country_name': $("#country_name").val()},
        success: function(response) {   
            $("#country_id").val() = response.country_id;
        }
    });
});
```

And my view is like this (linked to the same url in `urls.py`)

```
def get_country_id(country_name_get):
    countries = Countries.objects.filter(country_name=country_name_get)
    if countries.exists():
        for country in countries:
            country_id = country.country_id
    else:
        country_id = ''
return country_id
```

in my urls.py i have add this line :

```
url(r'^/country/getid/$', 'des.services.get_country_id', name='get_country_id'),
```

i have inspected the element with Google Chrome and then i see this error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
```

do you have any idea where the error came from ?

I still get nothing in the `country_id` input.
Is there a problem with my code or is there another solution for that?

Comment: @catherine i have edited the code (see above). I have added the comma to the url, method type and the datatype, but the error (Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .) still exist in line with $.ajax() declaration. any idea of the error where came from ?...the declaration in urls.py is like this : "url(r'^/country/getid/$', 'des.services.get_country_id', name='get_country_id'),"

Comment: @catherine yes the continuation is the DOT (.) "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token . " the same error with jsonp

Comment: should i add an external library to make the ajax() method work ?

Comment: no, there is something in your code that it needs to modified and I can't determine where it is.

Comment: no i didn't pass the country name with dot

Comment: your view in your question is that your current codes? because you need to pass `country_name_get`. I can't really determine the problem if your codes are incomplete

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your view does not return an `HttpResponse`. Moreover, you should return your `country_id` as JSON data. Assuming that each country name can only appear once in your database, your `for` loop in the view does not make any sense since you only retrieve the `country_id` for the last `country_name` that is in your queryset. Also, you should name your Django models always as singular words, not plural, that is, `Country` instead of `Countries`.

I would rewrite your AJAX function and your view like this:

```
$("#country_name").change({
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: "/country/getid/",
        data: {'country_name': $("#country_name").val()},
        success: function(response) {   
            $("#country_id").val() = response.country_id;
        }
    });
});
```

The view:

```
import json
from django.http import HttpResponse

def get_country_id(request):
    country_name = request.GET['country_name']
    response = {}

    try:
        country = Countries.objects.get(country_name=country_name)
        response['country_id'] = country.country_id
    except Countries.DoesNotExist:
        response['country_id'] = ''

    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response), mimetype='application/json')
```

Comment: i have follow exactlly the same code with datatype: "json" added to my ajax() call, but i still have an error with that (Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .) did i write it wrong !?

Comment: @LarbiMouhibbi forgot the comma at the end of url

Comment: @LarbiMouhibbi In which line does this `SyntaxError` occur? Your info is pretty useless if you don't tell us what causes this error.

Comment: @PeterStahl the error is in the line $.ajax({ it says that the problem is with the DOT (.) in the syntax ! "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token . "

Comment: @LarbiMouhibbi This is weird because the syntax is totally correct. Can you add the full stacktrace to your original posting?

Answer (score 1):

A view has to return an HttpResponse. The content of that response can be a simple ID, if you like, but it still has to be wrapped in a response.

```
return HttpResponse(country_id)
```

If you'd looked at the console, or the developer tools in your browser, you would have seen that the view was returning a 500 error. The browser tools would also have shown you the error traceback itself, which would have said exactly what I say above.

Comment: I've made the change to "return HttpResponse(country_id)", apparently there is a problem with my JS : "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ." do i need to rectify it ?

Comment: OK, you've updated the view to return JSON (which you didn't necessarily need to do, but it's a good way to pass data around). That means you need to tell the jQuery that you will be receiving JSON, so it knows to decode it. Add `datatype: "json"` to your `ajax()` call.

Answer (score 1):

Your url in ajax must have an app_name. I don't know what exactly the name of your app so I put `app_name` in my sample. Just change it with the correct one.

```
$("#country_name").change({
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/app_name/country/getid/",
        data: {'country_name': $("#country_name").val()},
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {   
            $("#country_id").val() = data;
        }
    });
});
```

you must pass the request, not `country_name_get`

```
def get_country_id(request):
    country_name = request.GET['country_name']

    try:
        country = Countries.objects.get(country_name=country_name)
        country_id = country.id
    except Countries.DoesNotExist:
        country_id = ''

    return HttpResponse(country_id)
```

In your url, I have doubt because of this `des.services.get_country_id`, it must be

```
 urlpatterns = patterns('app_name.views',
      url(r'^country/getid/$', 'get_country_id', name='get_country_id'),
 )
```

Or

```
 urlpatterns = patterns('',
      url(r'^country/getid/$', 'app_name.views.get_country_id', name='get_country_id'),
 )
```

depends on how you define it